# rails5-bootstrap-sass navbar responsiveness not working

Tags: css, sass, navbar, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-sass

Why is it that **navbar responsiveness** not working on Rails **5**. I am using `bootstrap-sass` gem. I've already search on the internet and tried for possible solutions yet I got no luck.

Here is my **/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 * 
 *
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: did you add `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` in your `application.js too?`

Comment: no, instead I added `//= require bootstrap`

Comment: you only need `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` in `application.js`

Comment: I change it already from `require bootstrap` to `require bootstrap-sprockets`  still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue earlier. I resolved it by adding these two lines in the `head` of `application.html.erb`

```
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```